# VBA Macros MSXML2.XMLHTTP Login

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

My first post on StackOverflow so please go easy on me :)

I'm an intern at a VR company and am trying to webscrape Spokeo.com for data. I have successfully extracted the correct data using XMLHTTP (as there is a large quantity of data being searched) but have come across an issue when not being able to read the information unless logged in.

E.G Searched term:7980 Sunset Blvd 
Result: Company ***** ***** *****, ***** *****.

If I manually log in and search for this location I can get all of the information censored by asterisks.

My Question is: How Can I log into Spokeo.com (similar script to google login forms) through MSXML2.XMLHTTP

I have already done a fair bit of research and come across this [article,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906564/login-into-website-using-msxml2-xmlhttp-instead-of-internetexplorer-application/35908113) but I'm unable to translate from the login of his example to mine because I can't code for shit! haha

This is the working code for my web scraping:

```
Sub GetOwners()
Dim URL As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHttp As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim var As String
Dim var1 As Object




lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

    URL = "https://www.spokeo.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHttp.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHttp.responseText
    Set objResultDiv = html.GetElementById("profile_selection")
    Set var1 = html.GetElementById("property_owners")

    Cells(i, 2).Activate

        If html.GetElementById("property_owners") Is Nothing Then

            Cells(i, 2).Value = "-"

            Else

            Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

            End If



    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
```

And this is my Frankensteinian attempt at taking Vitor Prado's code and applying for my application:

```
Sub testXMLHTTP()

Dim xml As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim dados As Object
Dim text As Object
Dim html2 As HTMLDocument
Dim xml2 As Object

Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Set html = CreateObject("htmlFile")


With xml
  .Open "GET", "https://www.spokeo.com/login?", False
  .send
End With

strCookie = xml.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")

html.body.innerHTML = xml.responseText

Set objvstate = html.GetElementById("__VIEWSTATE")
Set objvstategen = html.GetElementById("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")
Set objeventval = html.GetElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION")

vstate = objvstate.Value
vstategen = objvstategen.Value
eventval = objeventval.Value

'URL Encode ViewState
    Dim ScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set ScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
    ScriptEngine.AddCode "function encode(vstate) {return encodeURIComponent(vstate);}"
    Dim encoded As String
    encoded = ScriptEngine.Run("encode", vstate)
    vstate = encoded
'URL Encode Event Validation
    ScriptEngine.AddCode "function encode(eventval) {return encodeURIComponent(eventval);}"
    encoded = ScriptEngine.Run("encode", eventval)
    eventval = encoded
'URL Encode ViewState Generator
    ScriptEngine.AddCode "function encode(vstategen) {return encodeURIComponent(vstategen);}"
    encoded = ScriptEngine.Run("encode", vstategen)
    vstategen = encoded

Postdata = "__EVENTTARGET=" & "&__EVENTARGUMENT=" & "&__VIEWSTATE=" & vstate & "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=" & vstategen & "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" & eventval & "&ctl00$ddlTipoUsuario=#rdBtnNaoContribuinte" & "&ctl00$UserNameAcessivel=Digite+o+Usuário" & "&ctl00$PasswordAcessivel=x" & "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnNaoContribuinte" & "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$UserName=MYUSERNAME" & "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$Password=MYPASSWORD" & "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$Login=Acessar" & "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$txtCpfCnpj=Digite+o+Usuário"

Set xml2 = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Set html2 = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With xml2
  .Open "POST", "https://www.spokeo.com/login?", False
  .setRequestHeader "Cookie", strCookie
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Lenght", Len(Postdata)
  .send (Postdata)
End With

html2.body.innerHTML = xml2.responseText

Set objResult = html2.GetElementById("dadosDoUsuario")
GetElementById = objResult.innerText

MsgBox GetElementById

End Sub
```

There are a lot of references that I haven't changed purely because I don't know where to look.

I will still combine the two codes into one with the login being first once I know it will work individually.

Any help would be appreciated and I apologize in advance for my coding ignorance.

Cheers!

Comment: What is actual `strCookie` variable value? If there are several cookies, then you have to apply `.setRequestHeader` method for each cookie.

Comment: cookie_value so I'm guessing there is only one variable